# Why is the upper bound on the gaussian integral 2pi?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals, polar-coordinates, gaussian-integral

If you integrate the gaussian integral using polar coordinates you can convert into the following integral:

$$\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi} \int _{r=0}^{r=\infty} e^{-r^2}r dr d\theta=I^2$$

I get the conversion from -$\infty$ and $\infty$, to 0 and $\infty$ because radius is always positive but what about the theta bounds? The minimum angle of 0, if you draw out the graph of $e^{-x^2}$ the lowest angle you can go to is 0(As x approaches $\infty$ which is valid because one of the bounds are $\infty$) using this same logic shouldn't the other bound should be $\pi$?

Comment: The angles between $0$ and $\pi$ in polar co-ordinates cover for only the upper half-plane. To cover the entire plane $\mathbb R^2$ you need the angles between $0$ and $2\pi$ (or between $-\pi$ and $\pi$).

Comment: If that is the case then why do the bounds of the definite integral become 0 and pi/2 if the even property of an integral is used: $$4\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\pi/2} \int _{r=0}^{r=\infty} e^{-r^2}r dr d\theta=I^2$$

Shouldn't it be $\pi$ and 0?

Comment: @NpolaTheMathsGuy the even property of the integral is being used twice, hence the factor of $4$

Comment: Oh ok, now I understand. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the domain of the function that you are integrating matters here. In this case, that domain is $\Bbb R^2$. In particular, there are points of the domain all around $(0,0)$, and that's why we take $0\leqslant\theta\leqslant2\pi$. The same thing would have occurred if the domain was, say, the closed disk centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $1$. But if it was, say, $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid y\geqslant0\}$ (that is, the upper half-plane), then we would take $0\leqslant\theta\leqslant\pi$.